# Slow SQL query with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

**What my query is doing:**

I have two SQL tables and I want to copy datarows from the one table to the other table. I am doing this for statistics. The source table includes all current member-sessions/logins and with my statistics table I also want to see member-logins of the past. Thus I want to store these data into my bot_sessions_statistics table as well to make sure they are not being updated anymore:

**The original query:**

```
INSERT INTO bot_sessions_statistics (member_id, session_token, username, ip_address)
SELECT sessions.member_id, sessions.session_token, sessions.username, sessions.ip_address
FROM bot_sessions AS sessions
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT stats.member_id, stats.session_token, stats.username, stats.ip_address
    FROM bot_sessions_statistics as stats
    WHERE date_active >= date(NOW())
) AS stats
ON sessions.member_id = stats.member_id
WHERE latest_renewal >= date(NOW())
AND stats.member_id IS NULL
```

**The performance of the original query:**

```
Query_time: 86.364613  Lock_time: 0.000085 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1088312551
```

**The table structures:**

Table bot_sessions: 
[image: Table bot_sessions]

Table bot_sessions_statistics: 
[image: Table bot_sessions_statistics]

SHOW CREATE of both tables: http://pastebin.com/UUzEPX5v

**The performance of single queries:**

```
SELECT sessions.member_id, sessions.session_token, sessions.username, sessions.ip_address
FROM bot_sessions AS sessions
WHERE latest_renewal >= date(NOW())
```

Returns 44.2k rows (Duration: 0.078s / Fetch: 1.607s)

```
SELECT stats.member_id, stats.session_token, stats.username, stats.ip_address
FROM bot_sessions_statistics as stats
WHERE date_active >= date(NOW())
```

Returns 23.3k rows (Duration: 0.047s / Fetch 0.920s)

Comment: Have you considered partitioning your table by YEAR(date_active) or something? This will split the data files into specific file sets. I use it extensively for time series based analysis in mysql.

Comment: I can't do this because of other reasons/queries

Comment: Could you please post your table definitions as the result of "SHOW CREATE TABLE My_Table \G - this makes it easy to cut and paste, thanks.

Comment: @Vérace I have edited my thread and added this :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, run (and post the results here) an `EXPLAIN` on your query to see if indexes are being used or not.
At first, I see there are no other indexes on the *sessions* table except PKs, this will almost surely make your query run slow, since the `WHERE` will cause the RDBMS do a full table scan to find the rows.
I guess your query will at least require an index on `latest_renewal` (but, again, check with `EXPLAIN`).

This is my understanding of your query, on which I based my simplification:

```
SELECT sessions.member_id
    ,sessions.session_token
    ,sessions.username
    ,sessions.ip_address
FROM bot_sessions AS sessions
LEFT JOIN ( /* */
    SELECT stats.member_id
        ,stats.session_token
        ,stats.username
        ,stats.ip_address
    FROM bot_sessions_statistics AS stats
    WHERE date_active >= DATE (NOW()) /* a. I think this gives all of 'today' statistics */
    ) AS stats ON sessions.member_id = stats.member_id /* b. you're joining on 'member_id' which is NOT NULL in sessions, so any row from this subquery will have a value for (stats.)member_id */
WHERE latest_renewal >= DATE (NOW())
    AND stats.member_id IS NULL /* c. this will filter out all the rows from the JOIN, since no stats.member_id can be NULL */
```

Next, at first sight (if I'm not mistaken) I think your `SELECT` query can be rewritten without the `LEFT JOIN`, like this:

```
SELECT sessions.member_id, sessions.session_token, sessions.username, sessions.ip_address
FROM bot_sessions AS sessions
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM bot_sessions_statistics
        WHERE date_active >= date(NOW())
    )
AND latest_renewal >= date(NOW())
```

If the above is really correct, compare the results of `EXPLAIN` on both.

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer, I haven't seen EXPLAIN so far but I will provide the information for my query as well. I also checked the performance of your query which is much better (0.5s). Can you explain what SELECT 1 is doing?

I also tried to perform a query with `WHERE member_id IS NOT IN ( SELECT ... )`but it was even worse than my current query is.

Comment: By the way I am using MyISAM as Storage engine, as far as I know I can't create more than PKs with MyISAM or?

Comment: @kentor Then [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) and [this other](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-explain.html) link will give you lots of informations. `SELECT 1` just returns `1` from each row satisfying the `WHERE`, instead of the actual row data (that may be provided by an index or, worse from a performance point of view, could require physical access to the row), since you're not using that data - notice, however, that the optimizer could already be doing that for you. Nice, but please check carefully that my rewritten version is **really** correct.

Comment: @kentor About your second comment, you can add other indexes with *MyISAM* too - you're already doing that on the *bot_sessions_statistics* table :-)

Comment: This is the result of the Explain of your query: http://i.imgur.com/hRw7eex.png . I don't know how this should help now but the amount of rows should be ~17k for the primary query (after the where clause filtered the rows).

Comment: Unfortunately the query isn't correct at all. What exactly is it comparing with "NOT EXISTS" just the member_id or the whole primary keys?

Comment: @kentor I've commented on your query, see my edit.

Comment: In MySQL left join is usually preferred to not exists as it is better optimized in older versions.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the explain image above, the query is doing a table scan. (possible key and key are Null).
Rows_examined: 1,088,312,551  ( 1 billion rows examined, that's quite a lot, look like a cross join to me).
The second query (not exist) might not be right as it will exclude all data `FROM bot_sessions_statistics WHERE date_active >= date(NOW())` compare to a left JOIN (original query) which usually returns all rows, including the ones not matching the parent table criteria query.

Also for your sub-query, since you don't need session_token, username, you don't need it:

```
SELECT stats.member_id, stats.session_token, stats.username, stats.ip_address
FROM bot_sessions_statistics as stats
WHERE date_active >= date(NOW())
```

should be

```
  SELECT stats.member_id
    FROM bot_sessions_statistics as stats
    WHERE date_active >= date(NOW())
```

Tips: Try to avoid date > or date >= (and <  , <=). Mysql will scan the table.
Use between instead. Make sure you have index on these date fields.

Partitioning could also be a good solution.It's great for queries and for purging data.